# PySpark unable to read Avro file local from Pycharm

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a sample avro file and running a basic spark app to read it in:

```py
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("app") \
    .getOrCreate()

avro_data = spark.read \
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat") \
    .load("avro-to-orc-jobs/association-complete-rebuild/avro")
```

```
╰─ venv/bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.0 avro-to-orc-jobs/association-complete-rebuild/JobRunner.py─╯
```

This is my attempt to run it.

#### Error

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o29.load.
: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract scala.Option inferSchema(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession, scala.collection.immutable.Map, scala.collection.Seq)' of interface org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat.
```

I see that it downloads correctly. I've even tried adding it into `venv/lib/pythonx/site-packages/jars` and don't get any further there either.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? The answer by @vladsiv did work for me

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `format("org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat")`? Shouldn't it be just `format("avro")`? Ref: [Apache Avro Data Source Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html).

You could also define the package when you are creating a `Session`.

Dummy example:

- Write `avro` file:

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(
    "spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:2.4.4"
).getOrCreate()

data = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "A"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "B"},
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.write.format("avro").save("test")
```

- Read `avro` file:

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(
    "spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:2.4.4"
).getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format("avro").load("test")
```